# Dependency Injection (IoC) in JAVA + Azure Functions

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, inversion-of-control

I am using an Azure Function written in Java to retrieve the data from REST API and insert it into the mongo database.
I'm trying to separate the app into different layers like I usually do for web applications - for now I've only extracted the repository that stores the data in mongo into a separate class, so my function class looks like this (I've omitted triggers, error handlings etc)

```
public class SensorFunctions {

    @FunctionName("saveSensors")
    public void saveSensors(
        final ExecutionContext context) {
        SensorRepository sensorRepository = new SensorRepository();
        new SensorAPI().retrieveSensors()
            .forEach(sensorRepository::saveSensor);
    }
}
```

I'd prefer to use some king of IoC mechanism, so I don't have to instantiate repostiory and other classes by myself but I can do something like

```
public class SensorFunctions {
    @Inject
    SensorRepository sensorRepository;

    @Inject
    SensorAPI sensorAPI;

    @FunctionName("saveSensors")
    public void saveSensors(
        final ExecutionContext context) {
        sensorAPI.retrieveSensors()
            .forEach(sensorRepository::saveSensor);
    }
}
```

Is it possible with Azure functions? Is so, is it possible to create an automatic configuration or do I need to trigger the configuration of the IoC container manually at the beginning of each function (I will have multiple functions in a single project).
As the cost is dependent on the function's computation time, I'd prefer as lightweight solution as possible

Comment: I am not 100%, but I believe that at this moment there's no support for DI when writing your Azure Functions with Java (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/324)

Answer (score 1):

For now, you can use Spring Framework to use Azure Function for HTTP requests only (not the bindings.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/hello-spring-function-azure/hello-spring-function-azure/) is a sample on how to use it

I know there is a work in progress now to support Dependency injection for Azure Function [enter link description here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/324#issuecomment-719662979)

Answer (score 0):

The Java Developer reference for Azure Functions (
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java) now includes information, and an example for Guice and Dagger.

Example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/tree/dev/samples/dependency-injection-example